# How to properly dump ArrayList/RAW-drawn-image memory in Android?

Tags: java, android, memory-management

I am (still) working on a game, and as it nears completion, new problems arise. So here's the short story:
After fixing a few bugs and implementing new features, I may -or may not, have run into a small 'memory' issue. Each level has a set amount of time that the player has to solve it. When this time runs out, the level reloads. It is after this reloading, be it after failing to solve a level in time or after completing a level, that the game gradually starts slowing down. My timer ticks every second, the level reloads at the same speed, but when moving objects after X-reloads, they move more sluggish/laggish, as if skipping frames.
I have looked at my ArrayLists, and they are neatly (up for debate) empties, and my Timers are reset aswel. Below is some of the (relevant) code I'm using:

**OnTick() in my Update-timer**

*MoveObjects() moves all objects, updateDraw() updates the screen. This timer has a 15x1000ms timer with a 250ms tickspeed*

```
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        if(!loadingNewLevel)
            MoveObjects();

        updateDraw();
    }
```

**prepareNewLevel**

*This function prepares all necessary variables for a new level. It is called at both a level-reset and a level-completion*

```
public void prepareNewLevel(){      
    level.clear();
    movables.clear();
    totalSolved = 0;
    solvable = 0;
    levelWidth = 0;
    levelHeight = 0;
    allCollided = false;
}
```

**updateDraw(); refreshes the screen**

```
public void updateDraw(){   
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.game);
    rl.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    //Level
    for(GameObject go : level){
        ImageRAW(go.spriteID, R.id.game, go.position.x, go.position.y);
    }
    for(GameObject go : movables){
        ImageRAW(go.spriteID, R.id.game, go.position.x, go.position.y);
    }

    //Timer
    if(remaining_time >= 10000)
        TextViewRAW(TIMER_ID, R.id.game, 32, 32, "00:"+String.valueOf(remaining_time/1000)+"   Level "+String.valueOf(currLevel+1), 18, 0);
    else
        TextViewRAW(TIMER_ID, R.id.game, 32, 32, "00:0"+String.valueOf(remaining_time/1000)+"   Level "+String.valueOf(currLevel+1), 18, 0);
}
```

Now, the latter piece of code I posted is why I surmise something is wrong with my memory-management, as I am directly drawing on to the screen from my RAW folder. How do I handle the memory of directly-drawn RAW files, if this is the case?

I will also give you access to some of the relevant Java files:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kqu7sfi8qnlt9w6/Game.java?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ofpg1xj4anlvi0/UtilLib.java?dl=0

The latter of these files contains functions I'm using throughout the project, such as the ***ImageRAW()*** function mentioned earlyer.

-Zubaja

Comment: Your `updateDraw()` does not look like a routine you'd want to execute frequently. Do you really need to re-create and re-draw all the images on each timer tick? If you are reloading the resources each time, that alone would be a big CPU hog, let alone the vast amounts of memory that need to be collected.

Comment: That's true. Theoretically (and practically), all I would need to do is remove the Movable objects (which is significantly less than the level itself, sometimes as few as two objects) and re-draw those. However, as I am drawing them directy from my RAW folder, I have no idea how to do just those objects. I could try it with ImageViews, but I have no idea what sort of impact that would have. Or do you have a different advice?